# TypeError: encoding without string argument

Tags: python

## I can't see the problem

Hi, I have this function that converts a JSON dictionary to bytes. It then separates each element with `b'\x00\x00'`. I am doing this so that It can talk with a client I made for a game in Game Maker.

To better illustrate my problem I am going to use an example.This is the function that I am running `Encode({"header": 1})`.

Result I want `b'header\x00\x001\x00\x00'`

What I get `TypeError: encoding without a string argument`.

## What I have tried

I have tried debugging this on my own, but I just can't seem to find the problem at hand. One thing that I find odd is that if I put this line from my code in a `print` ( This is also the part that is causing issues). It works `print(buffer + bytes(_e,"utf-8") + b'\x00\x00')` but this  does not `buffer = buffer + bytes(_e,"utf-8") + b'\x00\x00'`.

## Code

```
# Encode function
def Encode(data):
    buffer = b''
    for e in data.items():
        for _e in e:
            buffer = buffer + bytes(_e,"utf-8") + b'\x00\x00'
    return buffer
```

Comment: *Great* question! This is the quality question we like to see on StackOverflow! Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code in order to get each pair of key-values and convert them to `bytes`. Keep in mind that you need to convert each value to string using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), before you convert them to bytes:

```
# Encode function
def Encode(data):
    buffer = b''
    for key, value in data.items():
        buffer = buffer + bytes(key, 'utf-8') + b'\x00\x00' + bytes(str(value), 'utf-8') + b'\x00\x00'
    return buffer

r = Encode({"header": 1})
print(r)
```

This will return:

```
b'header\x00\x001\x00\x00'
```